# jQuery find the value of a radio with a class name

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I'm trying to pull the 'data-val' of a radio that has a specific class name.

I need it to: Find the data-val of the element within a radiogroup that has the class 'correct'

I cannot for the life of me think of how to do this. Any thoughts?

HTML

```
<fieldset>
    <input type='radio' name='rads1' id='x1' data-val='23' class='correct'/>
    <label for='x1'>#1</label><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='rads1' id='x2' data-val='46' class='incorrect'/>
    <label for='x2'>#2</label><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='rads1' id='x3' data-val='16' class='incorrect'/>
    <label for='x3'>#3</label><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='rads1' id='x4' data-val='52' class='incorrect'/>
    <label for='x4'>#4</label><br/>
</fieldset><br/>
<fieldset>
    <input type='radio' name='rads2' id='y1' data-val='3' class='incorrect'/>
    <label for='y1'>#1</label><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='rads2' id='y2' data-val='6' class='incorrect'/>
    <label for='y2'>#2</label><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='rads2' id='y3' data-val='36' class='correct'/>
    <label for='y3'>#3</label><br/>
    <input type='radio' name='rads2' id='y4' data-val='12' class='incorrect'/>
    <label for='y4'>#4</label><br/>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using the **[`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/)** method:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=rads1].correct').data('val');
// Or [name=rads2] depending on which one you want...
```

[**<kbd>JSBin Demo</kbd>**](http://jsbin.com/akifuj/1/edit)

Comment: If I use your code, won't it pull the data-val from both radiogroups? I need it to pull from a specific radiogroup. (name=rads1) or (name=rads2). This is very very close though! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.correct').each(function() {
    console.log(  $(this).data('val'))
});
```

You would want to iterate over the elements as you might have multiple elements with same class.

Using **map**

```
var values = $('.correct').map(function() {
                return $(this).data('val');
            }).get();
console.log(values.join(','));
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/YG8PK/)**